# User input in my code is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

My assignment is to take an array of ten numbers of the user input, and then find the lowest and highest numbers.

I have done it according to class notes, but it is not working on netbeans.

```
import static java.lang.System.in;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindLargestSmallestNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //array of 10 numbers
        int numbers[] = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int i=0;

        for(int x=1; x<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
            System.out.println ("What is the "+ x +" number of the array");
            numbers [x] = in.nextInt( );
        }   

        //assign first element of an array to largest and smallest
        int smallest = numbers[0];
        int largest = numbers[0];

        for(i=1; i< numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] > largest)
                    largest = numbers[i];
            else if (numbers[i] < smallest)
                    smallest = numbers[i];
        }

        System.out.println("Largest Number is : " + largest);
        System.out.println("Smallest Number is : " + smallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) "not working" is not a sufficient explanation. 2) Java arrays are 0-based.

Comment: java arrays are 0-based, but you start saving numbers at position 1, so the `0` you initialized `numbers[0]` with will always be the smallest number. Plus, only saving 9 numbers, 1->9

Answer (score 2):

Array index starts from 0

In for loop start from index = 0 to index < 10

```
import java.util.*;
class MAXIMUMorMINIMUM{

    public static void main(String args[] ){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      //array of size 10
      int N = 10;
      int array[] = new int[N];
      for(int i = 0; i < N ;i ++){
        array[i] = in.nextInt();
      }

      int maximum = array[0];
      int minimum = array[0];
      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){

        //maximum
        if(array[i] > maximum){
          maximum = array[i];
        }

        //minimum
        if (array[i] < minimum) {
          minimum = array[i];
        }

      }

      System.out.println("MAXIMUM : "+maximum);
      System.out.println("MINIMUM : "+minimum);


    }
}
```

Comment: This only solves one of the several errors, and even so you didn't put it in the context of the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are incrementing `i` in the for loop and not `x` in the first for loop. That makes it run forever with `x==1`. Each time the loop code runs you are changing `i` which has no effect on the loop condition `x<numbers.length`.

You'll also want to start `x` at `0` instead of `1` since you index arrays starting at `0`.

also, inside that for loop `in` is actually `System.in` since you statically imported it. you should write `user_input.nextInt()` instead, since that the `Scanner` you made. This kind of thing should be obvious to you, especially if you are using an IDE that highlights the stuff for you like netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

The Code should look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //array of 10 numbers
        int [] numbers = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

        for(int x=0; x<numbers.length; x++)
        {
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
            System.out.println ("What is the "+ x +" number of the array");
            numbers [x] = user_input.nextInt();
        }   

        //assign first element of an array to largest and smallest
        int smallest = numbers[0];
        int largest = numbers[0];

        for(i=1; i< numbers.length; i++)
        {
                if(numbers[i] > largest)
                        largest = numbers[i];
                else if (numbers[i] < smallest)
                        smallest = numbers[i];
        }

        System.out.println("Largest Number is : " + largest);
        System.out.println("Smallest Number is : " + smallest);
}
```

As you created the Scanner Object and need to use it to get Input object from the user
Also to instantiate an Array you either call it like above or like the following:

```
int[] numbers = new int [10];
```

Also Arrays index start at 0 not at 1